# Recompiling node dependencies using another node version

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to install some dependencies and in this case installing node-pty. But when I run it they give me this error:

> Error: The module '/home/dev/Documents/project/node_web_kit/node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node'
>   was compiled against a different Node.js version using
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. Please try re-compiling or re-installing

any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to be sure is just to delete node_modules and re-run `npm i` from scratch, that way all modules will definitely be set up for the new Node version.

Comment: Thanks this is work. I didn't know whats going on. But I just upgrade my nodejs, clean my npm cache and run `npm i` like this

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles over this using WebStorm:

The terminal window in WebStorm uses system settings for node, but the run configuration could use a different version, so npm install in the terminal could lead to this error. Just change the node version in your run configuration and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the node-pty module using:

`npm rebuild node-pty --update-binary`

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above worked try rebuilding the package manually:

```
cd node_modules/<your module>
node-pre-gyp rebuild
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling doesn't work for you, nor `npm rebuild`, and you are using nvm, you might have a different problem.  Mine was that my npm config prefix was not set to my current nvm node version.  So you might try this:

```
npm config delete prefix
npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/vX.X.X
```

Of course, replace vX.X.X with the nvm installed node version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working on a Meteor project for the first time and didn't realize there was difference between `meteor npm install` and `npm install`. The former ensures that the correct packages get installed using the same `npm` version that has been tested with your current version of `Meteor`. My understanding is that this is common with other frameworks such as Electron.